# JS setInterval is being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, setinterval, es6-promise

I'm having following code

```
if (input.isValidLink()) {
  store()
    .then(db => db.update(message.from, text, json))
    .then(value => value.selectAllFromDB())
    .then(users => makeRequest(users));
}
```

Amd makeRequest function

```
makeRequest(user) {
  setInterval(() => {
    users.forEach(user => {
      httpRequest(user.json);
    });
  }, 10000);
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is `selectAllFromDB function` returns array of users from db, and it passed as argument to `makeRequest function`, which is looping thru each user, send request to receive `json` data and do it each 10 seconds, so it will not miss any changes. Each time when any user send the link, it should also start watching for this link. Problem is that on each received link it calls `makeRequest function` which creates another interval and if two links were received, I'm having two intervals. First looping thru this array

```json
[{
  id: 1234,
  json: 'https://helloworld.com.json',
}]
```

And second thru this

```
[{
  id: 1234,
  json: 'https://helloworld.com.json',
}, {
  id: 5678,
  json: 'https://anotherlink.com.json',
}]
```

Is there any way this can be fixed so only one interval is going to be created?

Comment: A general tip: A setInterval where you don't store the return value to be able to cancel it later on is almost always an error. In your case you should probably cancel the last interval and create a new once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this to make sure you only create one interval and are always using the latest users list:

```
let latestUsers;
let intervalId;
const makeRequest = (users) => {
  latestUsers = users;

  if (!intervalId) {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      latestUsers.forEach(user => {
        httpRequest(user.json);
      });
    }, 10000);
  }
}
```

If you don't want variables floating around you can use a self-invoking function to keep things nicely packaged:

```
const makeRequest = (() => {
  let latestUsers;
  let intervalId;
  return (users) => {
    latestUsers = users;

    if (!intervalId) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        latestUsers.forEach(user => {
          httpRequest(user.json);
        });
      }, 10000);
    }
  }
})();
```